# Why is bash not letting me edit this string?

Tags: string, bash, echo

The below echo keeps returning me a blank line. I don't understand why. Doesn't everything in bash act like a global variable?

```
# Deals with all the cases of having a file vs stdin
out_to_file="N"
#  Check to see if the user is running a file or just commandline input
if [ $# -ge 3 ];then
    out_to_file="Y" 
else  # The user is not running a file so ask them if they want to output to a file
    read -p "Output to a file? [y/n] " out_to_file 
fi
echo $out_to_file
```

Comment: Works fine for me.

Comment: run with `set -x` and see what's happening.

Comment: Are you typing any input after the prompt? Simply hitting enter assigns an empty string to `out_to_file`, rather than preserving its old value.